Why do "send USSD failed" notifications keep popping up?
SamsungS10e TruConnect network "send USSD failed" notifications keep popping up. Why?

We need more information

I have found two possible issues.

You are roaming and the firmware is not compatible
There is an app on your phone that is failing to connect.

Suggestions

Try wit roaming turned off, if you are roaming.
Try and remember the last few apps you installed and remove them.

